# Minus flag on list filter

Tags: freemarker

Working on some code and saw this:

```
<#list entity.fields(f- !f.isPrimaryKey) as field>
```

I know it is some kind of filter but I don't understand the f- flag. Looking on the documentation I did not see anything regarding that.

Comment: Do you mean `(f -> !f.isPrimaryKey)`? show more details as fields object

Comment: I think you are right, they gave me this code to fix and maybe they forgot to add the >. Thanks!

Comment: There are several suspicious things in that... Maybe it mean to be this: `entity.fields?filter(f -> !f.primaryKey)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the typo, you can use [lambda](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_lambda)

> The usage of lambdas is restricted to the parameters of certain built-ins, like: filter, map, take_while, drop_while.

For example as @ddekany comment

```
<#list entity.fields?filter(f -> !f.primaryKey) as field>
```

Where you are filtering fields list with non primary keys